# C++ map customize comparator

Tags: c++, dictionary

I defined a map to count the number of strings while sorting the strings by their length:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) {
        return a.size() > b.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    map<string, int, cmp> mp;
    mp["aaa"] = 1;
    mp["bbb"] = 2;
    cout << mp["aaa"];
}
```

I'm confused as the output is 2. How should I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way your comparator is defined, strings "aaa" and "bbb" are considered equal. Your map has one item, not two. First you assigned `1` to that item, then you assigned `2`.

To solve the problem, define your comparator as follows:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) {
        return a.size() == b.size() ? a > b : a.size() > b.size();
    }
};
```

That way, the strings will be considered equal only if they actually are equal, not only when their sizes match, but the string length will still have priority for sorting.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` not only sorts items by key, it **stores** them by (unique) key - 1 item per key.

This behavior is defined by the comparator: if for keys `a` & `b` neither of `a<b` and `b<a` is true, these keys are considered equal.

In your case `mp["bbb"] = 2` just overwrites `mp["aaa"]`.

If you want to fit all the strings in the map, you can use `std::multimap`, which allows more than 1 value per key.

The other way is to redefine the comparator, so that it would take the different strings into account:

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) {
        if(a.size() < b.size()) return true;
        if(b.size() < a.size()) return false;
        return a<b;
    }
};
```

Thus your map will still prioritize sorting by string length, but it will also distinguish different strings of same size.

Depending on your use case, you can also check other containers like `priority_queue` or just plain `vector` with a proper insertion technique.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! It's much clearer now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow strings of identical size in your map but do not care about their relative order, then [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) is an alternative solution:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        return a.size() > b.size();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::multimap<std::string, int, cmp> mp;
    mp.emplace("eee", 5);
    mp.emplace("aaa", 1);
    mp.emplace("bbb", 2);
    mp.emplace("cccc", 3);
    mp.emplace("dd", 4);
    auto const elements_of_size_3 = mp.equal_range("aaa");
    for (auto iter = elements_of_size_3.first; iter != elements_of_size_3.second; ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << " -> " << iter->second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
eee -> 5
aaa -> 1
bbb -> 2
```

From `std::multimap<std::string, int, cmp>`'s point of view, `"eee"`, `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` are all completely equal to each other, and `std::multimap` allows different keys to be equal. Their relative order is actually guaranteed to be the order of insertion since C++11.